# Java Applet can't receive mouse input under Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, input, applet

I have a `Java` applet that works fine under `Windows`.  It captures mouse and keyboard focus when it's clicked and everything is fine.  However, Under `MacOS`, this same applet doesn't capture keyboard or mouse focus except on a tiny UI item. focus.  Does anyone know of something simple that causes that, is a `MacOS` security settings?  Could it be because it was compiled on a `Windows 7` PC?

Comment: It will have less to do with how it is compiled then how the individual JVMs are implemented.  Some example code would go along way

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  It might help also to link to a 'live' version of the applet that we can see for ourselves.

Comment: I'm more of the web dev on the project.  I don't have immediate access to the source code.  I'll have to get back to you.  I've posted it on my own web site.  @Andrew Thompson [link](http://claygarland.com/sweethome/)

Comment: Note that an SSCCE is much more specific than 'the code', and is also much more useful than the actual link to a page (the 'link' was just 'extra info. that might come in handy').